# Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority when calling wcf service from metro app

Tags: wcf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am creating a Metro apps to read the data from WCF Service. The WCF service is using wsHttpBinding with certificate authentication. I am trying to read the certificate and validate the certificate at the Metro app.

In .net 4.0, `X509Certificate2` in `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` and `SslPolicyErrors` in `System.Net.Security` namespace was used for doing this. I am unable to find a `X509Certificate2` and `SslPolicyErrors` class in new Win 8 APIs to do that. What are the equivalent namespaces in Metro apps.